# Get files hashes with other attributes in Powershell

Tags: powershell, hash, compare

I need to get the `Date Created`, `Date Modified` alongside the file hash in Powershell, so my idea is to use this command

`gci  -Recurse | select Name, CreationTime, LastWriteTime` and append `Get-FileHash` either at the end or after the `get-ChildItem` and before the `Select`.

The problem, as I analyzed it, that `Get-FileHash` needs a path so it does not work if placed at the end, and it works but the `Select` fails if placed before.

Any idea how to solve it and is that the best way to compare dates or should they be converted to some other format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` with [a calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) - you'll have access to the path via the object piped down from `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |Select Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,@{Name='SHA256Hash';Expression={(Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $_.FullName).Hash}}
```

Comment: Impressive, but what about the date format, I run it for the same folder twice after editing a file, the `compare-object` didn't return anything, meaning they are identical which is not the case.

Comment: @user10191234 What date format? The `CreationTime` and `LastWriteTime` properties contain raw `[datetime]` values, you can format them however you like. How exactly are you comparing the outputs with `Compare-Object`? If I run the above pipeline, edit a file, and then run it again I certainly get a new `SHA256Hash` value for the file in question.

Comment: It is a cfg file, its hash didn't change, the `LastWriteTime` changed, when I did `Compare $a $b`, no output was there.

Comment: `Compare-Object` wouldn't tell. Is `$a.Hash -eq $b.Hash` `$true`?

Comment: `$a.SHA256Hash` -eq `$b.SHA256Hash` does not return anything, how to compare all properties?

Comment: Is `$a` and `$b` both the full ouput from the pipeline above? `Compare-Object $a $b -Property SHA256Hash -PassThru`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238648/discussion-between-user10191234-and-mathias-r-jessen).